# Build the matrix of all the combinations of given numbers using recursion [matlab]

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

Let say we have the vector `v=[1,2,3]` and we want to build the matrix of all the combinations of the numbers contained in `v`, i.e.

```
 1     2     3
 1     3     2
 2     1     3
 2     3     1
 3     1     2
 3     2     1
```

Since I'm not good in recursion, firstly I tried to write the code to build such a matrix by using `for` loops

```
makeLoop([1,2,3])

function A = makeLoop(v)
    loops=length(v);
    for i = 1:loops
        dummy=v;
        m=factorial(loops)/loops;
        A((1+m*(i-1)):m*i,1)=v(i);
        v(i)=[];
        loops2=length(v);
        for j = 1:loops2
            dummy2=v;
            m2=factorial(loops2)/loops2;
            A(((1+m2*(j-1))+m*(i-1)):(m2*j+m*(i-1)),2)=v(j);
            v(j)=[];
            loops3=length(v);
            for k = 1:loops3
                m3=factorial(loops3)/loops3;
                A(((1+m2*(j-1))+m*(i-1)):(m2*j+m*(i-1)),3)=v(k);
            end
            v=dummy2;
        end
        v=dummy;
    end
end
```

it seems like it work, but obviously write it all for a bigger `v` would be like hell. Anyway I don't understand how to properly write the recursion, I think the recursive structure will be something like this

```
function A = makeLoop(v)
if length(v)==1
    "do the last for loop"
else
    "do a regular loop and call makeLoop(v) (v shrink at each loop)"
end
```

but I don't get which parts should I remove from the original code, and which to keep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close! The overall structure that you proposed is sound and your loopy-code can be inserted into it with practically no changes:

```
function A = makeLoop(v)
% number of (remaining) elements in the vector
loops = length(v);

if loops==1 %"do the last for loop"
    A = v; %Obviously, if you input only a single number, the output has to be that number

else %"do a regular loop and call makeLoop(v) (v shrink at each loop)"
    %preallocate matrix to store results
    A = zeros(factorial(loops),loops);
    %number of results per vector element
    m = factorial(loops)/loops;

    for i = 1:loops
        %For each element of the vector, call the function again with that element missing.
        dummy = v;
        dummy(i) = [];
        AOut = makeLoop(dummy);
        %Then add that element back to the beginning of the output and store it.
        A((1+m*(i-1)):m*i,:) = [bsxfun(@times,v(i),ones(m,1)) AOut];
    end
end
```

#### Explanation `bsxfun()` line:

First, read the [`bsxfun` documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), it explains how it works way better than I could. But long story short, with `bsxfun()` we can replicate a scalar easily by multiplying it with a column vector of ones. E.g. `bsxfun(@times,5,[1;1;1])` will result in the vector `[5;5;5]`. Note that since Matlab 2016b, `bsxfun(@times,5,[1;1;1])` can written shorter as `5.*[1;1;1]`

To the task at hand, we want to add `v(i)` in front (as the first column) of all permutations that may occur after it. Therefore we need to replicate the `v(i)` into the 1. dimension to match the number of rows of `AOut`, which is done with `bsxfun(@times,v(i),ones(m,1))`. Then we just horizontally concatenate this with `AOut`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ohh it was just `A = v` in the `if` statement...simpler than I thought! Could you explain the line `[bsxfun(@times,v(i),ones(m,1)) AOut]` ? You are creating a matrix but I never seen the `bsxfun` before, how does it work?. Anyway thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [perms function](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html) to achieve this:

```
v = [1 2 3];
perms(v)

ans =
      3     2     1
      3     1     2
      2     3     1
      2     1     3
      1     3     2
      1     2     3
```

If you want them sorted using the same criterion you applied in the desired output, use the following code (refer to [this page](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) for an official documentation of the `sortrows` functon):

```
v = [1 2 3];
p = perms(v);
p = sortrows(p)

p =   
    1     2     3
    1     3     2
    2     1     3
    2     3     1
    3     1     2
    3     2     1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already know about the perms function, but I'm trying to understand how the recursion would work in this case, because I have to solve a more difficult problem that it is conceptually similar to the problem in my question, but in which I cannot use the perms function. I have to use recursion because the number of loops depend on the size of a certain matrix.

Comment: Ok the problem here is that part of the inner loops depend on the outer ones (see `j`)... actually, more than a recursion I would say you need to implement the same logics over and over until the condition is exhausted (for example, the columns of `v` to be used within the computation). An alternative would be vectorizing everything... I have to think about how to do it, and honestly if I don't know what you are trying to do it will be hard for me to figure out.